# What widths and heights for landscape mode in swift?

Tags: swift, autolayout

I just started working with Auto Layout and my app will be in landscape mode. The app must be available for iPhone and iPad. What settings do I need to set for this? any - any in Auto layout? It should support iPhone 5 and later. And when I add a custom font in a text to my project in Any - Any, it looks of course smaller on an iPad because the screen is bigger. When I adjust the font to Regular width and any height and test it, it custom font is disappeared. Is this because I am using the wrong settings now? And when I insert an image, will it automatically be bigger on iPad?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there can be a lot of width/height settings for just "landscape mode, iPhone 5 or later".

If you open an interface builder file, you can click on the "w**Any** h**Any**" thingy to see what settings are suitable for what device.

For example, in the screenshot here, The settings "Regular Width | Compact Height" are for 5.5 inch phones in landscape mode:

[image]

If you don't know what size each iPhone model is, here's a simple chart:

```
Size (in)    Model
3.5          4S
4            5
4.7          6S
5.5          6S Plus
```